# System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml is a type not a namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I'm including this line:  `using System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml;` in order to make the below code work.

```
SqlXml sqlXml = reader["ScenarioData"].GetSqlXml();
```

The `GetSqlXml();` error is solved by including the above using line, but then I get the error that "`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml` is a type not a namespace"

Am I missing a dll reference or something?  I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not like Java, you don't import separate classes. You import whole namespaces. Try this instead:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
```

Alternatively, if you **really** want to follow Java rules, use this code instead:

```
using SqlXml = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml;
```

Comment: Cool.  So I included that, but then `GetSqlXml();` throws that the  "'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetSqlXml' and no extension method 'GetSqlXml' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Hubrid Could you tell me what the output of `reader["ScenarioData"].GetType().ToString()` is?

Comment: If I replace the line with your line above, I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml'... confused what you're asking.

Comment: @Hubrid No, I just want the output of that. That way I can help you with your second problem.

Comment: If I write `var bob = reader["ScenarioData"].GetType().ToString();`, the bob comes out to be null.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Hubrid Yes. Thanks. Hmm, try asking another question. I have no idea how SqlDataReader works.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlXml` is a type, not a namespace.

use this instead: `using System.Data.SqlTypes;`