# 'Object' does not contain a definition for 'GetSqlXml'

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Visual Studio is not liking this code.  =(

```
SqlXml sqlXml = reader["ScenarioData"].GetSqlXml();
```

It hates the `GetSqlXml();` part, and is throwing the error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetSqlXml' and no extension method 'GetSqlXml' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I think I'm including all of the necessary references and namespaces and dll files but I just can't get VS to recognize the function.  What are my next steps?

Comment: What's the type of `reader`?

Comment: you just asked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841342/system-data-sqltypes-sqlxml-is-a-type-not-a-namespace

Comment: Please read the comments he said create new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide the column index ([the `GetSqlXml` method belongs to SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlxml.aspx)):

```
SqlXml sqlXml = reader.GetSqlXml(0);
```